# Деньга́ми или де́ньгами?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия

В справочной литературе написано, что вариант **де́ньгами** — устаревший, тем не менее, с экрана часто можно слышать именно это ударение.
Как же все-таки правильно: **деньга́ми** или **де́ньгами**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А так и правильно, как вы написали. Оба варианта на настоящий момент считаются возможными. Вариант дЕньгами — устаревает, но окончательно ещё не вытеснен.
Кстати, помета "устар" в словарях обычно означает "устаревает", не устаревшее. Для последнего используется "стар".

Answer (score 1):

Как вы понимаете, орфоэпические нормы не начинают действовать с момента их закрепления в словарях. Очень долгое время люди употребляют привычные им старые нормы, считая новые безграмотными. Но нормы вводят не лингвисты. Они лишь фиксирую преобладающий вариант. Еще лет 15 назад  деньгАми считалось ошибкой. Если сейчас в словарях дЕньгами отмечается как устаревший вариант, значит, вариант деньгАми "превысил критическую массу" и теперь считается признанным литературным.